# PC stuck at boot after displaying PXE information

Tags: bios, uefi, pxe

The PC hangs forever after displaying the following two lines:

```
Intel(R) Boot Agent GE v1.3.27
Copyright (C) 1997-2008, Intel Corporation
```

Pressing the keys usually bound to BIOS or UEFI functions (<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>...) before or after has not effect.

The keyboard seems to be stuck, pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> or <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> does not change the status of the corresponding status LED.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to a faulty memory module. Since the memory is an essential part of the computer, there is no other solution than to investigate on the hardware level.

- pull the power cable out
- open the PC case
- remove a module
- plug the power cable in
- boot and see if it helps
- repeat for the other modules

If the computer has only one module, you will have to find a spare one to test.

Comment: While the site doesn't mind self-answers, the idea usually is that a self-answer should describe what the _actual_ solution to the problem was, not just the usual wild guess.

Comment: This is not a wild guess, it was the actual solution in my case. But I can imagine this is not the only one, since the symptoms are far from an unambiguous error message.